# Qual valor é verificado em uma operação de condição com atribuição de valor a uma variável?

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis

Tenho um método que faz uma verificação e o retorno desse método armazeno em uma variável do tipo `bool`.

Quando executo essa operação o C# testa o valor da variável ou o valor do retorno do método?

Exemplo:

```
 bool retorno = default(bool);
 if ((retorno = conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text))))
 {          
      // regra de négocio
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você tem que olhar a tabela de precedência e associatividade de operadores.

Os parênteses usados já dão uma garantia de tudo o que está dentro dele será executado antes e o resultado desta expressão toda é que será usada pelo `if`. Portanto

Dentro desta expressão toda tudo o que está do lado direito do `=` será executado primeiro já que a associatividade é da direita para a esquerda. De qualquer forma também demoraria para executar a atribuição já que ela tem precedência baixa.

Pegando a expressão `conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text))` primeiro executará o `.` já que ele tem a precedência máxima junto com parenteses. Ele vai primeiro porque a associatividade é da esquerda para a direita, e ele está mais à esquerda. O mesmo vale para o que está dentro de cada parênteses. Então a execução será:

```
temp = txtValor.Text
temp = Convert.ToDouble(temp)
temp = conta.Saca(temp)
retorno = conta.Saca(temp)
if (retorno)

using System;

public class C {
    public static int Main() {
        var conta = new Conta();
        var txtValor = new Form();
        bool retorno;
        if ((retorno = conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text)))) {
            Console.WriteLine(retorno);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
     }
}

public class Conta {
    public bool Saca(double x) => true;
}

public class Form {
    public String Text;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gJapk2). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oW1r28). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Precedence.cs).

De fato o IL mostra isso:

```
IL_000b: ldloc.0              //bool retorno;
IL_000c: ldfld string Form::Text //txtValor.Text
IL_0011: call float64 [mscorlib]System.Convert::ToDouble(string) //Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text)
IL_0016: callvirt instance bool Conta::Saca(float64) //conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text))))
IL_001b: dup                  // Duplicate the value on the top of the stack
IL_001c: stloc.1              //retorno = conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text)))
IL_001d: brfalse.s IL_0027    //if ((retorno = conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text)))) {
```

Veja [completo no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMCAbJmAHbCYCyAhnQBQCUhxpvAbswBOmAMYB7es0wBeTLQCmAdzwTgzTgG4evEgOHAAHsABqzCGOGyFygGIWAtpu06ARmLERMg+cAu0xWiiYAJDBYABmmGxs3r6C/jKiqswAdADKzCLquBJ88oLAKQAqYgAiYgCuLhDybIYmZhbF8kYcbVxEQTrdMADsmAiB3SQAvs68fZgADEO8YyjzqBjYcCqS3F0ky24emBlZbAAmldXymAZc0gB8mMCCFfKBi2jkq3aC9hsTWGl3dADmmCKLWATyAA=).

Tabela de precedência:

| Categoria | Opradores | Associatividade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Postfix | () [] -> . ++ - - | Left to right |
| Unary | + - ! ~ ++ - - (type)* & sizeof | Right to left |
| Multiplicative | * / % | Left to right |
| Additive | + - | Left to right |
| Shift | << >> | Left to right |
| Relational | < <= > >= | Left to right |
| Equality | == != | Left to right |
| Bitwise AND | & | Left to right |
| Bitwise XOR | ^ | Left to right |
| Bitwise OR | | | Left to right |
| Logical AND | && | Left to right |
| Logical OR | || | Left to right |
| Conditional | ?: | Right to left |
| Assignment | = += -= *= /= %=>>= <<= &= ^= |= | Right to left |
| Comma | , | Left to right |

Answer (score 4):

O Codigo ira testar o valor da variavel retorno, que no caso recebeu o valor de retorno do metodo

```
bool retorno = default(bool);
if ((retorno = conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text))))
```

é equivalente a

```
bool retorno = default(bool);
retorno = conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text));
if (retorno)
```