# Quais benefícios de utilizar o operador => em métodos comuns que não tenham relação com Listas ou Expressão Lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, operadores, método

Fiz a seguinte pergunta: [Qual valor é verificado em uma operação de condição com atribuição de valor a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206902/d%C3%BAvida-de-qual-valor-%C3%A9-verificado-em-uma-opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-atribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de/206912?noredirect=1#comment423254_206912)
e o usuário @Maniero me respondeu, porém, na resposta ele utilizou um operador e isso me gerou uma nova dúvida. Questionei o mesmo sobre o uso do operador e ele me indicou o seguinte link para esclarecimento: [Qual é a finalidade do operador => no uso de listas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99379/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-operador-no-uso-de-listas/99382#99382). Porém, ainda não está claro para mim.

Quais os benefícios de utilizar o operador `=>` em métodos que não tenham relação com listas ou expressão lambda?

Se o operador não tem relação com listas e nem com expressão lambda. Como a operação seria chamada no caso de não ser ou não ter relação com uma função anônima?

Tentei executar o seguinte código em ConsoleApplication, porém, da erro de declaração do operador =>, dizendo que é esperado o ";". Se esse operador tem essa função não deveria apresentar tal erro.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class C
    {
        public int Main() {
            var conta = new Conta();
            var txtValor = new Form();
            bool retorno;
            if ((retorno = conta.Saca(Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text)))) {
                Console.WriteLine(retorno);
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
         }
    }

    public class Conta {
        public bool Saca(double x) => true;
    }

    public class Form {
        public String Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: É só pra encurtar o código.

Comment: Tudo bem, porém, não funciona da forma que o @bigown explicou, ou eu entendi / testei  errado

Comment: Ou você não está usando o C# 6 (?)

Comment: Não, estou usando o 2012 no caso, vou testar com o 2017

Comment: Isso só passou a existir no C# 6.

Comment: Entendi, não sabia disso. Vou testar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neste caso não é um operador, é só uma construção da linguagem para simplificar a escrita de métodos que contenham apenas uma linha.

Isto foi introduzido em C# 6 para métodos normais e no C# 7 foi disponibilizado para os demais métodos como propriedades, construtores, destrutores e eventos. Não funciona em versões anteriores.

Ele não tem nada de especial na linguagem, não faz nada novo, não muda semântica alguma, é apenas uma mudança sintática.

```
public bool Saca(double x) => true;
```

é exatamente o mesmo que:

```
public bool Saca(double x) {
    return true;
}
```

Ele tem um `return` implícito. Mas funciona com um método que retorne `void`  também.

Obviamente só pode ter uma linha.

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var objeto = new Exemplo(42);
        objeto.Imprime();
        WriteLine(objeto.Executa());
        WriteLine(objeto.Executa2());
        objeto.Prop = 42;
        WriteLine(objeto.Prop);
        objeto.Prop = 12;
    }
}

public class Exemplo {
    private int prop;
    public int Prop { get => prop; set => prop = value == 42 ? value : throw new ArgumentException("Tem que ser 42 ", nameof(Prop)); }
    
    public Exemplo(int x) => prop = x;
    
    public void Imprime() => WriteLine("ok");
    public string Executa() => "texto";
    //public bool Teste2() => WriteLine("ok2"); return true; //daria erro
    public string Executa2() { //é a mesma coisa
        return "texto";
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Or85au). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m23toV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/BodyExpression.cs).

Comment: Agora ficou claro, simplifica muito na hora de escreve métodos com uma única linha de código. Aprendi algo novo. Obrigado pela explicação.